# Multiple sql query or Cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help on something that seems to be complex to me.

I made a query to create a tbl1 which is the Cartesian product of the tables Item and Warehouse. It give’s me back all items in all warehouses:

```
SELECT i.ItemID, w.WarehouseID
FROM Item i, Warehouse w
```

I made a second query (tbl2) where I check the date of the last document previous or equal to a variable date (@datevar) and whose quantity rule is 1 (PhysicalQtyRule = 1), this by Item and Warehouse, obtained from StockHistory table

```
SELECT MAX(CreateDate) AS [DATE1], ItemID, Quantity, WarehouseID
FROM StockHistory
WHERE PhysicalQtyRule = 1 AND CreateDate <= @datevar
GROUP BY ItemID, Quantity, WarehouseID
```

Now, I need more three steps:

1. Build a third table containing per item and warehouse the sum of quantity, but the quantity rule is 2 (PhysicalQtyRule = 2) and date between tbl2.date (if exists) and the date of the variable @datevar, obtained from the table StockHistory. Something like that:

   ```
   SELECT ItemID, WarehouseID, SUM(Quantity)
   FROM StockHistory
   WHERE PhysicalQtyRule = 2 AND CreateDate > tbl2.DATE1 --If exists
   AND CreateDate <= @datevar
   GROUP BY ItemID, WarehouseID
   ```
2. Build a fourth table containing per item and warehouse the sum of quantity, but the quantity rule is 3 (PhysicalQtyRule = 3) and date between tbl2.date (if any) and the date of the variable @datevar, obtained from the table StockHistory. Something like that:

   ```
   SELECT ItemID, WarehouseID, SUM(Quantity)
   FROM StockHistory
   WHERE PhysicalQtyRule = 3 AND CreateDate > tbl2.DATE1 --If exists
   AND CreateDate <= @datevar
   GROUP BY ItemID, WarehouseID
   ```
3. Create a final table based on the first one, with an sum quantity column, something like that:

   ```
   SELECT i.ItemID, w.WarehouseID, tbl2.Quantity + tbl3.Quantity – tbl4.Quantity AS [Qty]
   FROM Item i, Warehouse w
   ```

I don't know if need cursors (something new for me) or multiple querys, but it's important the best performance because my StockHistory table have millions of records.

Can anyone help-me please? Thank you!

Some sample data, only for one Item and one warehouse:

```
+--------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
| ItemID | WarehouseID | CreateDate | PhysicalQtyRule | Quantity | Balance | comments 
+--------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
|   1234 |          11 | 2013-03-25 |               2 |       35 |      35 | Rule 2 = In 
|   1234 |          11 | 2013-03-28 |               3 |       30 |       5 | Rule 3 = Out
|   1234 |          11 | 2013-04-01 |               1 |        3 |       3 | Rule 1 = Reset
|   1234 |          11 | 2013-07-12 |               2 |       40 |      43 | Rule 2 = In 
|   1234 |          11 | 2013-09-05 |               3 |       20 |      23 | Rule 3 = Out
|   1234 |          11 | 2013-12-31 |               1 |       25 |      25 | Rule 1 =  Reset
|   1234 |          11 | 2014-01-09 |               3 |       11 |      14 | Rule 3 = Out
|   1234 |          11 | 2014-01-16 |               3 |        6 |       8 | Rule 3 = Out
```

I want to know the balance on any variable date.

Comment: Are you trying to get just that final query as a result of all this table creation or do you need to actively store all that data?

Comment: Only need the final query. Made all this steps to try the best explanation.

Comment: Could you give some sample data and expected results?

Comment: PLease start to use explict joins, implicit joins can cause lots of maintenance headaches and they are just simply a SQL antipattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your data, I can't test this but I believe this should be your solution.

```
SELECT i.ItemID
    ,w.WarehouseID
    ,[Qty] = tbl2.Quantity + tbl3.Quantity – tbl4.Quantity
FROM Item i
CROSS JOIN Warehouse w
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT [DATE1] = MAX(sh.CreateDate)
        ,sh.ItemID
        ,sh.Quantity
        ,sh.WarehouseID
FROM StockHistory sh
WHERE sh.PhysicalQtyRule = 1 AND sh.CreateDate <= @datevar
AND i.ItemID = sh.ItemID
    AND w.WarehouseID = sh.WarehouseID
GROUP BY sh.ItemID, sh.Quantity, sh.WarehouseID ) tbl2
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT sh.ItemID
    ,sh.WarehouseID
    ,[Quantity] = SUM(sh.Quantity)
FROM StockHistory sh
WHERE sh.PhysicalQtyRule = 2 AND sh.CreateDate > tbl2.DATE1 --If exists
AND sh.CreateDate <= @datevar AND i.ItemID = sh.ItemID
AND w.WarehouseID = sh.WarehouseID
GROUP BY sh.ItemID, sh.WarehouseID ) tbl3
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT sh.ItemID
    ,sh.WarehouseID
    ,[Quantity] = SUM(sh.Quantity)
FROM StockHistory sh
WHERE sh.PhysicalQtyRule = 3 AND sh.CreateDate > tbl2.DATE1 --If exists
AND sh.CreateDate <= @datevar AND i.ItemID = sh.ItemID
    AND w.WarehouseID = sh.WarehouseID
GROUP BY sh.ItemID, sh.WarehouseID ) tbl4
```

Comment: I don't know why but the query didn't recognize tbl2.DATE1 (both near "If exists") and alias tbl3 and tbl4...

Comment: And warehouse table don't have ItemID field. My first query was "perfect" (I think) because I want all Items x All Warehouses, but I can get it from this query too:    `SELECT ItemID, WarehouseID FROM StockHistory GROUP BY ItemID, WarehouseID`

Comment: @PJLG You can take out the `ON` clause for the `CROSS JOIN`.  It is the same execution plan as your query, just a little more readable IMO.  Still looking into the other issue.

Comment: @PJLG Updated answer.  Had the `ON` when `OUTER APPLY` uses a `WHERE` inside.  Moved it around and aliased everything.  Try it again.

Comment: I´m sorry, but I didn't reach that. I understand the `CROSS JOIN` but changing `WHERE`by `ON` (is that?) don't change anything. I add some sample data.

Comment: I think the problem was here: `[Qty] = tbl2.Quantity + tbl3.Quantity – tbl4.Quantity`. Some of these values are NULL. I change for `[Qty] = ISNULL(tbl2.Quantity,0) + ISNULL(tbl3.Quantity,0) – ISNULL(tbl4.Quantity,0)` and it work's fine. Now, I'm analysing all data to find other issues (I hope not). Thank you!!!

Comment: It's perfect now! Only need to change `tbl2.DATE1` to `ISNULL(tbl2.DATE1,0)` because it doesn't calculate the rows without `DATE1`. Thank you again @TTeeple!